# How can I get the rupees from the fishhead-like entrance eyes in Floria waterfall?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Replaying the game in hard mode, and I'm trying to be very thorough and discover things I missed the first time. I've got all dowsing abilities enabled, and I'm dowsing for rupees and treasure, mostly to discover breakable walls or hidden stuff I missed. This way, I discovered that there are flags in Skyloft that can produce rupees using the gust bellows, fires in alcoves produce rupees if blown upon too, lanterns produce rupees if hit with deku seeds etc.

At the Floria waterfall, the large fishhead-like entrance has two large eyes that seem to be active when dowsing for rupees, but I can't get these rupees. I've tried the clawshots from the closest lilly (too far), arrows, beetle to no avail.

Does anyone know how to get the rupees from the eyes of the fishhead entrance;

Comment: I was going to recomend beetle...

Comment: …but then you noticed I already tried it?

Comment: I recall collecting these with the beetle, very odd.

Comment: I see that others maybe had success with the beetle; I'll try again, then. As I was closing in with the beetle, I remember that the left eye of the fish (right eye as we see it) seemed to be covered by an ice-like haze (penetratable, not an obstacle), but I didn't have success in either eye.

Answer (score 1):

The beetle is what I used. If its fully upgraded it works a lot better.

Answer (score 0):

slingshot for a blue rupee that falls into the water and is difficult to reach in time. not worth it. BUT there is a gold one on a ledge in the southeast corner [use the beetle :)]